# Translating text from database

Tags: django, django-i18n

I'm modeling a service catalog where I group services in different categories. Each category is a model with a description among other fields that are not relevant here.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    ...
```

The idea is that additional service categories (or even sub categories) are added as the platform grows.
I need to have the description in several languages.

I've considered different approaches to do so, and I need to decide which one is cleaner.

**First approach**.
Model descriptions as db models with the description and a language so I cal filter using the lang code and edit them on the admin

```
class CategoryDescription(models.Model):        
    description = models.TextField()
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    describes = models.ForeingKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):        
    ...
```

**Second approach**.
Remove the description field and use the title of the category as contextual marker. Something like

```
class Category(models.Model):        
    one_word_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

And then in the templates.

```
{% trans "category_description" context category.one_word_name %}
```

However, my concern here is, Is there an automatic way to generate the ids to be marked as translation? How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

To translate your model there is a very useful package I recommend you to check:

- [Django ModelTranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation)
- [Django ModelTranslation Docs](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Django Model Translation installation](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

With this package you can mark your models for translation, you should follow the tutorial is pretty easy

Anyway the most important steps are:

1. Install the package with: `pip install django-modeltranslation`
2. Add `modeltranslation` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`
3. Set `USE_I18N = True` in settings.py.
4. Configure your LANGUAGES in settings.py.
5. Create a translation.py in your app directory and register `TranslationOptions` for every model you want to translate.
6. Sync the database using `python manage.py syncdb`

---

## Examples

**LANGUAGES in your settings.py:**

```
LANGUAGES = (
        ('de', gettext('German')),
        ('en', gettext('English')),
    )
```

**`translation.py` example:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Model Translation
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from models import *


class MyModelTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name', 'description')   # Select here the fields you want to translate  
translator.register(MyModel, MyModelTranslationOptions)

# You can add as many models as you want to translate here
```

---

After you define everything and sync the database, the models you choose to translate will have their fields translated.

If you have a field called `description` and you mark it as translations, if you're using English and German, django model translation will create the fields `description_en` and `description_de` where you can add the translations.